# ASP.NET MVC Localization with SEO in mind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I have found several options how to properly localize my asp.net mvc project, but still have some doubts selecting the right one.

Want to mention that I need to localize site the way i would be still able to make SEO optimizations for each language separately

Here are the options i found:

1. ***First***: create a subdomain for different culture:

   mysite.com - for default language and

   it.mysite.com - for italian language
2. ***Second***: Create new route with subfolder querystring, like

   mysite.com/default - for default language and

   mysite.com/it/default - for italian language

There are no problems on implementing first option.

And if the second option is more preferable... could anyone describe how it should be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what SEO effect you wanna achieve. But generally if all pages are on the same domain, it's better for SEO => mysite.com/it/default is better

Except if you have a real local business, then you could even go with different top level domains. E.g. mysite.de and mysite.it

In therms of MVC:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{languageCode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { languageCode = @"de|fr|en|it" },
    namespaces: new[] { "SupertextMvc.Controllers" } // only map routes to controllers in the specified namespace
    );
```

This is our routing configuration

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question to clarify things: All links on the site are set without languageCode part. For example: you search to www.site.com/it, and then you want to go to the inner page like www.site.com/it/about. But the link you're going to click written this way: www.site.com/about. Should I redirect users in action filter attribute to proper link by adding /it/about? Or all the links should be regenerated to reflect the valid full path for current language?

Comment: I would not do the redirects. If you can, I would just use relative links instead of absolute ones. Then you have it easier. Otherwise, yes, regenerate them.